# Has anybody [interpreted] the purpose of this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [interpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreted) tag has 33 questions and no wiki. It's a very ambiguous tag and the questions tagged with it vary greatly in topic.

Questions include:

- [Can you convert literal string to an interpreted string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008555/can-you-convert-literal-string-to-an-interpreted-string-in-php)
- [How is machine language run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600162/how-is-machine-language-run)
- [IIS doesn't interpret a php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581442/iis-doesnt-interpret-a-php-file)
- [How to use Subversion for non-compiled language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252987/how-to-use-subversion-for-non-compiled-language)

If a question is about language interpreters, then the much more popular [interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreter) tag can be used instead.

Should we burninate this tag?

Comment: I wonder if some questions are being mistaken for [tag:interpreted-language].  Then I wonder if *that* tag is useful too.

Comment: Comments continue to overthink what a tag is for. A tag is applied to an individual **question**.  Use of any tag (now specifically speaking of the _interpreted-language_ tag) is not a declaration of the deeper meaning of what a language is, nor some kind of statement about the limits of whether it can be compiled or interpreted, etc. No matter how interesting the debate is, we do not have to come to any super-specific definition of an interpreted vs compiled language. As long as the **question** regards any aspect of a language that is interpreted, the tag can be used to indicate the context.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143293/discussion-on-question-by-aaron-christiansen-has-anybody-interpreted-the-purpo).

Comment: I think the first question is someone who meant _interpolated._ I have very little experience with PHP, but that is my impression.